# Disable cursor ring for tablet in Windows 7/8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, tablet

When I installed my Bamboo tablet in Windows 7/8, a ring shows anytime I click with the pen. Which annoys me.

Comment: I put the question and my answer here as the tip for other users as I spent quite a lot of time finding a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a new option. Wacom recenly (June 2013) released a new driver: Version 6.3.6-w3

The new driver seems to completely disable the pen rings and works in both Windows 7 and Windows 8 - I've tried it on 3 Windows 8 machine and 2 Windows 7 machines and can confirm its behavior on Intuos 4 and Intuos 5 tablets.

To use the new Driver:

- Install the Driver (you will be asked to reboot if you already have a previous driver)
- From the **Start Menu** or the **Control Panel** go to **Wacom Tablet Properties**
- For **Tablet**, select your tablet device
- For **Tools**, select your pen
- For Application, select **All**
- Then select the **Mapping** tab
- At the bottom left of the Mapping tab, uncheck **Use Windows Ink**
- Close **Wacom Tablet Properties**
- You are done - you should see no more **dynamic feedback/ripples** or other effects such as **drag-delay** or **press-and-hold**

More details are here: http://viziblr.com/news/2013/6/24/the-windows-and-wacom-tablet-nightmare-is-over.html

Answer (score 8):

### Windows 7

I have found the solution:

1. Open *Local Group Policy Editor*. It is quite hidden - search for it in Windows Start menu or in Control panel - use the search box as I have not found the shortcut for it. Alternatively you can run `gpedit` from command line (not from Run in Start menu).
2. Navigate to User *Configuration - Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Tablet PC - Cursor*.
3. Enable the *Turn off pen feedback* setting.

### Windows 8

See [Windows 8 RTM and Wacom Tablets - Even More Flawed Than Before](http://viziblr.com/news/2012/8/18/windows-8-rtm-and-wacom-tablets-better-but-flawed.html)

My current solution is to install old drivers: [DRIVER 5.24-6 RC FOR WINDOWS 7, VISTA (32 AND 64 BIT) AND XP](ftp://ftp.wacom-europe.com/pub/WINDOWS/cons524-6_int.exe)

Comment: This works only in Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate, Home and variations don't have the Local Group Policy Editor.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions involving the Group Policy Editor will work for Windows Professional and Ultimate. But it doesn't work on Windows 7 Home Premium - because Home Premium doesn't have a Group Policy Editor.

Essentially you'll need to modify the registry to disable the rings. There's a REG file at the bottom at the link below that will do this for you

http://viziblr.com/news/2011/8/14/the-ultimate-guide-to-making-your-wacom-tablet-work-on-windo.html

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest driver from Wacom and go to the Mapping tab and uncheck the Use Windows Ink box - hey presto circles have gone. Too simple, but took Wacom long enough to get there

Answer (score -1):

In 8.x, go to `control panel` -> `pen and touch.` In the pen options under the `press and hold` section, click settings and uncheck `press and hold`. Tested and worked for me.